# EclipseLink cache invalidation with stored procedure

Tags: oracle, jpa, eclipselink

Given that we're using eclipselink on oracle database:
1. we have some data from table A cached in JPA cache
2. we're calling a stored procedure, which modifies data in table A

Will be the JPA cache informed (through database event) that the data in table A changed (will it be invalidated)?

Answer (score 0):

No, JPA is unaware of any changes made to the database outside of JPA queries, or through other persistence contexts, or even the same contexts on different JVMs.  There are many ways to deal with this though, such as invalidating and managing the cache yourself:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/Expiration

Or registering EclipseLink with the database to listen for change events:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/DatabaseEvents

You might be better of though just making the changes through JPA where ever possible.